# Run python every 2 seconds

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I know how to start a function every x seconds or minute. The main problem is that it happens that my script stops for « no reason » or that windows crashs. Ram was ok at that time. I can’t let this happens. So instead of running the script forever and call a function every 2 or 3 seconds to check my gmail emails or make it sleep every 2 seconds, I am looking for one of these alternatives :

- Windows: at email reception (gmail), run my script and read its header
- Windows: open and run the script every 3 seconds to check for new emails then close it.
- Other alternatives (web service or other)

Zapier was a good alternative. At email reception (api) run python. But it’s not possible to import library so that doesn’t fit my needs.

I’m working on MacOS so I know I have the possibility to run it with crontab but this not an option since I don’t want to make it run forever on my desk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the shedule library: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.
Here it's an example:

```
import schedule

schedule.every(interval).seconds.do(function)
while True:
     schedule.run_pending()
```

You need to install the library: `pip install schedule`

Comment: Does it execute every x seconds? (Or minimum is  minute?)

Comment: Also with seconds. Changed it in the question.

Comment: Ok. What is the difference with sleep() ?

Comment: Being honest, I don't really know how it works but I've used it a lot and I haven't had any problem with it.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to try it and get back here in a moment

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to deploy on Pythonanywhere, you can schedule a task/run a script every x. https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/ScheduledTasks/